# Newrelic performance testing ,SpringServlet.Service() consums most time

Tags: sql, spring, jersey, newrelic

I am using newrelic to test my project performance.But the result is that springServlet.Service() consums most time in jersey rest service.I do not konw why.
What is in springServlet.service().

```
Slowest components  Count   Duration    %
SpringServlet.service() 1   5,300 ms    98%
ActivityResource$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$821c53dc.retrive()   1   27 ms   0%
activity_picture - SELECT   10  23 ms   0%
activity_trail_type - SELECT    10  17 ms   0%
activity_holiday_type - SELECT  10  16 ms   0%
activity_user - SELECT  10  14 ms   0%
Remainder   1   25 ms   0%
Total       5,420 ms    100%
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend opening a ticket with us at https://support.newrelic.com/ for this so we can take a better look at your account in detail.

Answer (score 0):

New Relic released version version 3.1.1 of the Java agent about a week ago, with a number of bugfixes for Spring instrumentation. It's very likely that an upgrade will fix this issue. [Release notes are here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/releases/java), and all you need to do to update is replace your newrelic.jar and restart your JVM.